# to think of something in a different light

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective: a way to describe an era I am writing about as a "not well understood" precursor to current times.

Comment: You **see** something in a different light.

Comment: An _obscure_ precursor to current times ?

Answer (score 1):

"I am writing about a **[neglected](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/neglected)** precursor to the current times".

> To pay little or no attention to, the state or fact of being neglected